# How do I properly use async and await when getting data from my firebase db?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to fetch json data from my realtime db in firebase and set a variable to it. I tried doing that in the code below

```
useEffect(() => {
  let database = firebase.database();
  database.ref().on('value', async (snapshot) => {

    await setQuestions(snapshot.val());
    console.log('questions here ', questions)
  }) 
},[]);
```

The console.log outputs questions here null, instead of logging the actual data. I know this is a issue involving the order the lines are being executed because I've proven that I am actually pulling the data from the database. It's just not finishing pulling it where I need it to.
From my understanding, await would stop execution within the async block until the line of code with await on it finished. However, that's not happening. So either I misunderstood how async functions work or I'm not putting the async or await keyword where I need to be. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: questiona is defined. In my code it appears as below

```
const [questiona, setQuestions] = useState(null);
```

Comment: Have you checked that setQuestions is returning a promise?

Comment: does questiona get set in setQuestions?

Comment: questiona doesn't seem to be defined.

Comment: @controlaltdel questiona is defined. I just edited the original post to show how I initialized it. I set it as null which explains why the console.log returns null when I try to print questiona. The problem is that I can't seem to set questiona to the snapshot.val() when I need it to.

Answer (score 0):

`await` has no effect unless the value on the RHS is a promise.

`setQuestions` is, I assume, the set part of a `useState` hook. It does not return a promise.

(**If** it did then the `questiona` variable (which I assume is the data part of that hook) would not update in the current scope anyway.)

---

If you want to see what `questiona` is, then log it on the next render of the React component you are working in.

---

```
const [questiona, setQuestions] = useState(someDefaultValue);

console.log(questiona);

useEffect(() => {
  let database = firebase.database();
  database.ref().on(
    'value', 
    (snapshot) => setQuestions(snapshot.val())
  ); 
},[]);
```

Comment: RHS means react hook state I'm assuming? I initialized ```questiona``` the same way you did, except I set it to null, which explains why the console logs null. So, since ```await``` and ```async``` aren't useful here, how would I set ```questiona``` to ```snapshot.val()``` so that ```questiona``` isn't null when I need to use it?

Comment: RHS means Right Hand Side

Comment: You set it as you are already (or as I am in this example). (This assumes that the callback function does get called and `snapshot.val()` returns a useful value). You need to account for `questiona` being `null` on the first render of course (e.g. display a loading message).

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean now. It takes 3 renders for it to be set to what I need it to be. Also, quick question. I put another console.log right outside the useEffect method. So now I have the original console.log in my code and the new one. The output is

``` 
null, 
null, 
Finally set to content of DB, 
questions here null
```
How come the console.log inside the method shows ```questiona``` as null but the console.log outside it shows it the contents of the DB?

Comment: Inside `useEffect` it runs when the component is first rendered (when it is null) and then again when it is re-rendered *and* the dependencies change … and since your dependency list is empty, that is never.

Answer (score -1):

The issue in the above code is that, when we declare any function as async, it returns a promise.

You need to create a separate async function outside useEffect and call it from the useEffect.

Comment: Why is that an issue? Does `database.ref().on()` have a problem if the second argument returns a promise?